How to solve appcompileflutterbuilddebug that is many time occur in our app when we run old project
Where:
Script 'C:\Users\admin\fvm\cache.git\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1629

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\admin\fvm\cache.git\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

flutter clean
flutter pub get 

above that I tried but I am failed
In android I tried android enable true

it's suggests  to run this command flutter pub upgrade --major-versions as it downloads and install outdated packages, Then I do Invalided Caches & restarted AS

it's suggestion is helpful but sometimes this error is happening in vs code  then I do in android and do invalided Cache & restart.

In Answer to above question is that Invalid cache and restart in android studio.
flutter clean
flutter pub cache clear
flutter pub get

When you run old project then project run in old version of flutter so try to run project in latest version of flutter using fvm.
